# How to call another method with same arguments using `when/then` mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following setup:

```
class Foo{

    public Foo addDate(String str, Date d){
    .....
    }
    public Foo addString(String str){
    .....
    }
}


class Bar{

    private Foo foo;

    public void bar(){

        foo.addDate(x, x);
    }

}


class testBar{

   //test bar()

}
```

When writing a test case for the usage of the above, how can I use when/then to call `addString` whenever `addDate` is called but using the same argument.

Is something like this possible using mock or spy?

```
when(foo.addDate("myString", any())).thenReturn(foo.addString("myString"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `thenAnswer`, where you can write a lambda that takes an `Answer` object as parameter where you can extract the arguments of the call to `addDate`:

```
when(foo.addDate(eq("myString"), any()))
    .thenAnswer(answer -> 
            foo.addString(answer.getArgument(0)));
```

Have a look at the docs [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Just one extra issue. When I use `any()` it throws an exception because internallly, it has a `notNull` check. How can I pass a not null value as `any()`

Comment: Perhaps it's a different problem, which I added here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590430/any-not-passing-the-notnull-check

Comment: Right. You have to use a matcher also for the literal String. Use `eq` (see my edited response)

Answer (score 0):

> When writing a test case for the usage of the above, how can I use when/then to call addString whenever addDate is called but using the same argument.

I am not sure what you actually mean by above so I decided to cover the cases that occurred to me with a working example, in comments is the system output for each test:

```
public class TestIt {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    // A bit modified version of your class
    public class Foo {
        public Foo addDate(String str, Date d) {
            System.out.println("addDate(..) should not be called, not mocked?");
            return this; // need to return a Foo :)
        }

        public Foo addString(String str) {
            System.out.println("addString(\"" + str + "\")");
            return this;
        }
    }

    // To call the real method you need the spy so you can mock only
    // methods that needs different functionality 
    @Spy
    private Foo mockFoo;

    // answer that uses param in method invocation
    private Answer<Foo> answer = invocation -> 
            mockFoo.addString(invocation.getArgument(0));
    // answer that calls with fixed param, not using the invocation 
    private Answer<Foo> staticAnswer = invocation -> 
            mockFoo.addString("myString");

    @Test
    public void testAnswer() {
        System.out.println("testAnswer");
        doAnswer(answer).when(mockFoo).addDate(any(String.class), any(Date.class));
        mockFoo.addDate("add me", new Date());
        // testAnswer
        // addString("add me")
    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticAnswer() {
        System.out.println("testStaticAnswer");
        doAnswer(staticAnswer).when(mockFoo).addDate(any(String.class), any(Date.class));
        mockFoo.addDate("add me", new Date());
        // testStaticAnswer
        // addString("myString")        
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyString() { // same as Ruben's answer, only react when myString
        System.out.println("testMyString");
        doAnswer(answer).when(mockFoo).addDate(eq("myString"), any(Date.class));
        mockFoo.addDate("add me", new Date());
        mockFoo.addDate("myString", new Date());
        // testMyString
        // addDate(..) should not be called, not mocked?
        // addString("myString")
    }

}
```